Vico charts android: markerVisibilityListener parameter
I am using Vico charts library for android jetpack compose. When implementing a CartesianChartHost, there are parameter called markerVisibilityListener. Can someone help me with an exemple. The user clicks on the chart, the chart shows a marker. How do i put the data of the marker in the Logcat. Thx for the help.
In markerVisibilityListener parameter, i don t know what to do
CartesianChartHost(
        chart =
            rememberCartesianChart(
                rememberCandlestickCartesianLayer(),
                startAxis = rememberStartAxis(),
                bottomAxis =
                    rememberBottomAxis(
                        guideline = null,
                        itemPlacer =
                            remember { AxisItemPlacer.Horizontal.default(spacing = 3, addExtremeLabelPadding = true) },
                    ),
            ),
        modelProducer = modelProducer,
        marker = marker,
        markerVisibilityListener = , // Here i don t know what to do
        modifier = modifier,
        horizontalLayout = HorizontalLayout.fullWidth(),
    )


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

You need to implement the object : CartesianMarkerVisibilityListener {}
inside this you can override the onShown, onUpdated and the onHidden methods.
Besides the marker, onShown and onUpdated will include a List<CartesianMarker.Target> which will include the information you want to log, but they need to be casted accordingly to the proper target type.
In my specific case i have a LineChart where i'm interested in the highlighted point and i always only need one (the last one) of them. So this is what i implemented to get my highlighted x/y values:
markerVisibilityListener = object : CartesianMarkerVisibilityListener {
            private fun List<CartesianMarker.Target>.lastEntry() =
                (lastOrNull() as LineCartesianLayerMarkerTarget?)?.points?.lastOrNull()?.entry

            override fun onShown(marker: CartesianMarker, targets: List<CartesianMarker.Target>) {
                targets.lastEntry()?.let {
                    onHighlightChanged?.invoke(it)
                }
                super.onShown(marker, targets)
            }

            override fun onUpdated(marker: CartesianMarker, targets: List<CartesianMarker.Target>) {
                targets.lastEntry()?.let {
                    onHighlightChanged?.invoke(it)
                }
                super.onUpdated(marker, targets)
            }
        }

As you can see in my lastEntry extension function i'm explictly casting to LineCartesianLayerMarkerTarget, since i'm only using a LineChart. Since you're using a CandleStick chart you probably need to use a CandlestickCartesianLayerMarkerTarget instead.
